# Can I bind asp.net dropdownlist using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, drop-down-menu

Can I bind asp.net dropdownlist using javascript/jquery? I get the data from jquery ajax from a web method so I want to avoid postback at this point. But I still want to do postback and save all the data using server side code (i.e. I still be able to do this `dropdownlist1.selecteditem.text`) after binding it using clientscripts.

Is it possible and can someone explain me how it can be done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use Json ajax

Syntax:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: url,
data: data,
success: success
});
```

See simple example for json:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var msgbox = $("#status");
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",

                    //Page Name (in which the method should be called) and method name
                    url: "BeginJson.aspx/CheckDateTime",
                    // If you want to pass parameter or data to server side function you can try line
                   // data: "{}",
                    //else If you don't want to pass any value to server side function leave the data to blank line below
                    data: "{'args':'Somnath'}",


                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (msg) {
                        //Got the response from server and render to the client
                        msgbox.html(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: I have tried many things and finally gave up the idea to do this. The problem was the event validation failed once an asp.net control has been altered. i.e. I will never be able to use 2 technologies together. I can't rewrite all the server code so I gave up the idea of doing partial ajax. Thanks.